# How with PhpStorm in 1 *.scss file to show classes with the same name?

Tags: phpstorm

Working with .scss files in PhpStorm 2021.1.4 in some cases I have problems as there are several classes in
1 *.scss file. For *.scss file that is allowed, but can I in PhpStorm to to show such cases, say as some command ?

Thanks!

Comment: What you mean "show"? You mean list all duplicate class selectors? If so - I don't think PhpStorm has such feature.

Comment: Yes, I mean duplicate class selectors. Somethimes it can be reason of errors in my scss code

Comment: Hit `CTRL + F` and select class string to find, check amount of found items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such feature in the IDE, please vote for [WEB-74](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-74) to be notified on any progress with it